# Generar código qr que acceda a una página web cuando se escanea

Tags: php, php5, php7

Tengo que generar códigos qr de manera que cuando se escanee acceda a una página la cual se conecta a una base de datos y checa si el código escaneado está guardado, esto tengo que hacerlo con php

Tengo este codigo php:

```
<?php
include_once("phpqrcode/qrlib.php");

$dir = "temp/";

if(!file_exists($dir))
    mkdir($dir);

$filename = $dir."prueba.png";

$tamano = 10;
$level = "H";
$frameSize = 3;
$contenido = "http://midominio.mx/checar.php?var=05f4cd55";

QRcode::png($contenido, $filename, $level, $tamano, $frameSize);

echo "<img src='".$filename."'>";
?>
```

Si genera el código qr pero cuando lo escaneo haciendo uso de un lector qr que descargue en mi celular solo me muestra el contenido y no accede a la página del contenido para conectarse a la base de datos y hacer la validación.

Comment: Debería mostrar la URL en el Scanner, ¿qué obtienes actualmente , a que te refieres con contenido? o intentas que el navegador se abra automáticamente?

Comment: @Dev.Joel contenido es lo que está codificado y exacto lo que intento es que se abra automáticamente

Comment: Suena a problema o configuración del Scanner, por lo general solo muestran la URL más no se abren automáticamente. Y esto escapa de las manos de PHP.

Comment: @Dev.Joel yo quiero hacer algo como whatsapp, cuando abrimos el portal web de whatsapp nos pide escanear el código qr, una vez que lo escaneamos nos da acceso al chat, eso es lo que quiero hacer.

Comment: Me parece que vas a tener que hacer la app de android ;P